# Can't connect to Docker container from local machine

Tags: docker

I have encountered a strange behaviour. I have running grafana container with tcp/3000 exposed

```
# docker ps -a | grep grafana
26fa0fff9220   registry:4000/prometheus/grafana    0/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   grafana

# docker inspect grafana -f '{{json .NetworkSettings.Ports }}'
{"0/tcp":null,"3000/tcp":[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0","HostPort":"3000"}]}

# ss -tunlp | grep 3000
tcp     LISTEN   0        4096             0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:*      users:(("docker-proxy",pid=3051799,fd=4))
```

The problem is that although curl works correctly for localhost it doesn't work when i am using the address of the host machine's network interface.
For example

```
//works fine
root@host-1# curl localhost:3000
<a href="/login">Found</a>.

//doesn't work at all (10.25.200.111 is eth-interface ip address on this same host), curl hangs indefinitely
root@host-1# curl 10.25.200.111:3000
^C
```

If i make a request from another host to 10.25.200.111:3000 it works without problems.

```
root@host-2# curl 10.25.200.111:3000
<a href="/login">Found</a>.
```

What am i doing wrong or maybe missing?

Comment: What does `nslookup 10.25.200.111` on the docker host return?

Comment: @Turing85 
Well, it returns the name of the docker host - host-1

Comment: What about `curl http://host-1:3000`? Or `curl http://$(hostname -f):3000`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer both of them don't work.  Similar to `curl 10.25.200.111:3000`